# Describe array transition with specific commands

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Lets suppose we have two integer arrays, for example:

```
var A = new int[] {1, 4, 6, 12, 44};
var B = new int[] {2, 4, 6, 44, 45};
```

The problem is to describe a transition steps as:

Starting with the array `A` and continue as following:

- STEP 1 : `remove index = 0             // result = {4, 6, 12, 44}`
- STEP 2 : `insert index = 0 value = 2   // result = {2, 4, 6, 12, 44}`
- STEP 3 : `remove index = 3             // result = {2, 4, 6, 44}`
- STEP 4 : `insert index = 4 value = 45  // result = {2, 4, 6, 44, 45}`

And we now have the array `B`

My Question is: How can I design this algorithm in any programming language or pseudocode that generates these steps programatically for given array A and B?

common step structure is like :

STEP N : `insert/remove index = i [value = v]`

Of course removing all elements from `A` then inserting all elements from `B` is a solution and like that maybe there will be more than 1 solutions for given `A` and `B`, but I am looking for the transition with the fewest steps.

Answer (score 0):

There is the concept of the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It is used for comparing two strings (however you can also apply the same principle to integer arrays): minimal number of edits to change one string into another, where one edit is either a deletion, an insertion or a substitution.

The problem can be efficiently solved using **dynamic programming**. The wiki article shows such an approach.
You can use the same approach for your problem. But since in your case you are not allowed to substitute an element (only remove and insert operations), you can even simplify the the recursion a (tiny) bit:

```
def edit_distance(s, len_s, t, len_t):
    if len_s == 0:
       return len_t
    if len_t == 0:
       return len_s

    if s[len_s-1] == t[len_t-1]:
        return edit_distance(s, len_s-1, t, len_t-1)
    else:
        return min(edit_distance(s, len_s-1, t, len_t) + 1, 
                   edit_distance(s, len_s, t, len_t-1) + 1)
```

The code above is without dynamic programming. To make it efficient, you need to add it.

Also, the code will only compute the number of steps. If you also want to list the steps, you have to store the complete table and backtrack the solution.

Time and memory complexity of the approach: O(len_s * len_t).

---

Here is an example using your two arrays `[1, 4, 6, 12, 44]` and `[2, 4, 6, 44, 45]`. Here is a table that you would get if you apply dynamic programming (e.g. with a bottom first approach) for each of the possible prefix-combination of the strings.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 3 2 3 4 5 
3 4 3 2 3 4 
4 5 4 3 4 5 
5 6 5 4 3 4
```

At the bottom right we see that 4 is the optimal number of steps to make both array equal. Now we can backtrack and look at the recursive formula again. Since the last two elements are not equal, it has to be an insert/remove operation. We can see in the table the optimal number of steps for `[1, 4, 6, 12], [2, 4, 6, 44, 45]` is `5`, and for `[1, 4, 6, 12, 44], [2, 4, 6, 44]` is `3`. So the optimal thing here is to remove the last element of the second array, or in other words to insert `45` in the first one.

Now we can thing about the last step that resulted in `[1, 4, 6, 12, 44], [2, 4, 6, 44]`. Since the last elements are equal, the step is clear. We leave both of them and perform no insert or remove operation.

So what was the last step in `[1, 4, 6, 12], [2, 4, 6]`? The table shows that the optimal value 3 originated from the position `[1, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]`, which means a removing `12` in the first array.

And so on.

Interestingly there can be multiple optimal solutions. Here I show you one possible path (which corresponds exactly to your solution):

```
0-1 2 3 4 5 
  |       
1 2 3 4 5 6 
   \      
2 3 2 3 4 5 
     \    
3 4 3 2 3 4 
      |   
4 5 4 3 4 5 
       \  
5 6 5 4 3-4
```

Comment: Lets suppose that we included substitution and  have found count of steps with Levenshtein distance algorithm.
How can we brute-force for example 3 steps of solutions ?
Pls share If You have any idea Bcs lets say we found 1 insert,1 update,1 delete operations needed.Then we can brute force delete operation but cant do it with insert operation bcs we need to know what to insert/update

Comment: @RaminRahimzada I added an example to my explanation.
Notice: my implementation still doesn't use DP (although it is only 1-2 lines of code). So if you are unfamiliar with dynamic programming, you should learn it before. This is actually a very classical problem, and you will find it in nearly every basic algorithmic course.